# Creating subfolder alias on .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an URL like this: `mydomain.com/app/index.php`.

Now I have to create an `alias` for the subfolder `app`. It needs to be created through `.htaccess`, because the site is hosted on a shared server.

Is there a way to create this `alias` so users can access the site using both **mydomain.com/app/index.php** and **mydomain.com/alias/index.php**?

It's important that the **domain/subfolder** part of the URL does not change during user navigation.

I've tried some examples from other questions but all of them make a redirection, changing the URL to **mydomain.com/app/index.php** when I hit **mydomain.com/alias/index.php**.

Thanks in advance!

[]'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^alias/(.*)$  app/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like a good night's sleep to make us see our problems from a different perspective.

If someone comes up with the same problem, I managed to solve it using symlinks and PHP global var `$_SERVER`.

First I created a symlink from subfolder `app` to `alias` (I had to do it using a PHP script, as I don't have ssh access to the server):

`ln -s /var/www/project/app /var/ww/project/alias`

After that, I changed the lines of code that had `www.mydomain.com/app` hardcoded to get domain and subfolder from the URL passed in the request:

```php
$urlWithSubfolder = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
header('location: https://' . $urlWithSubfolder . '/login.php");
```